# Structure for 3 or more tables with relationship

Tags: sql

I need help about database structure,

so I need to join 3 tables but I'm confuse what structure is the right way.

**Region_table**

```
id     region_name
1      Region1
2      Region2
```

**Province**

```
id    province_name
1     Province1
```

**City**

```
id     city_name
1      city1
```

I'm thinking to create new table that connects all.

like `id, region_id, province_id, city_id`

**region_province_city**

```
id    region_id    province_id    city_id
1     1            1              1 
2     1            1              2
```

or I can do like

**Province**

```
id    province_name  region_id
1     Province1      1
```

**City**

```
id     city_name     province_id
1      city1         1
```

Comment: region_province_city will help you in directly having a relation between region and city without including province; But totally depends on how you want to work with this data; Also add usecase is it heavy on reads or writes?

Comment: I'm also thinking about that also if which is better in terms of read or write. I need ad day to read articles about this hehe

Comment: I find it easier/better to try and reflect reality in the database model, then worry about efficiency and other issues when (if) they come up.  So if a city is always in one province and a province is always in one region then your second model makes more sense and helps enforce that logic more directly.

Comment: @IanMcGowan yes, it make more clear thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally suggest the hierarchical structure.  That is, adding the parent id to each of the two tables.

Why? This guarantees that the region on a given province is always the same.  That can be hard to guarantee in the 3-way junction table.  After all, you don't have an *independent* relationship among the three entities.  You have a *hierarchical* relationship and you would like to enforce that data integrity.

An example of an independent relationship would be:

- Customers
- Items
- Payment Method

Presumably a customer could purchase any item using any payment method -- and even use different payment methods on the same item.

Would I *always* recommend this structure?  Well, no.  If the data is not being modified, then you are pretty safe with the three-way table.  It works very well for looking up information about a "city".  It can be verified when created.  And it might provide some simplification (particularly if the hierarchies are deeper).

That said, it works best when your joins are to the lowest level.  It is a little tricky to get the region for a province.  A typical solution would be to augment the data with `NULL` values for `city` to get that information.